# How to track if an app is launching for the first time in Android?

Tags: android

I am developing an app in which for **only** the **first** time it is launched, I want to perform some actions. Now I considered using **Shared Preferences** till I hit the dilemma that I'd have to initialize that on Oncreate itself, and every time I launch the app, the shared preferences would be overwritten.

So, I am considering checking whether a particular type variable itself exists on the **Shared Preferences** or not, but I am stuck there too. Now is there a simpler way that I am overlooking?

Comment: put the init code of your shared preference in an if else block, check what the value of Shared preference is!

Comment: did you mean you dont want this if(!prefs.getBoolean("firstTime", false)) {// Code run for first time}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this first time SharePrefrences Code:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        if (!prefs.getBoolean("Time", false)) {

                           // run your one time code

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("Time", true);
            editor.commit();
        }
```

This sharedpreference is run only one time when first time is application is launched.
This is work for me.

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to check like this..

```
/**
 * checks for the whether the Application is opened first time or not
 * 
 * @return true if the the Application is opened first time
 */
public boolean isFirstTime() {
    File file = getDatabasePath("your file");
    if (file.exists()) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

if the file is exist its not the first time other wise its the first time..

Comment: This is  a pretty nice way too!

Comment: One more thing want to add, if file not exist then create new one otherwise this code every time return true.

Answer (score 0):

SharePreferences is a good choice.

```
public class ShortCutDemoActivity extends Activity {

// Create Preference to check if application is going to be called first
// time.
SharedPreferences appPref;
boolean isFirstTime = true;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Get preference value to know that is it first time application is
    // being called.
    appPref = getSharedPreferences("isFirstTime", 0);
    isFirstTime = appPref.getBoolean("isFirstTime", true);

    if (isFirstTime) {
        // Create explicit intent which will be used to call Our application
        // when some one clicked on short cut
        Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                ShortCutDemoActivity.class);
        shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        Intent intent = new Intent();

        // Create Implicit intent and assign Shortcut Application Name, Icon
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "Shortcut Demo");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,
                Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(
                        getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.logo));
        intent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
        getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(intent);

        // Set preference to inform that we have created shortcut on
        // Homescreen
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = appPref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("isFirstTime", false);
        editor.commit();

    }
}
```

}

And modify your Androidmanifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
```